# Delphi 7 - Checking a Letter with TMemo.Lines

Tags: delphi-7

I currently have set of words inputted inside my MemoBox.
Question is how do I check the specific letters on each lines of the TMemobox Lines property. If letter is not similar on the word being specified then it should be wrong and not be counted in and if answer correct how to let the word appear on the wordlabel?

Also how to limit the guess-label property into only inputting 5 letters?
Currently making a hang-man game :)

[Set of Words here](https://gyazo.com/9bcb8b54ceacedc0c8347f864d3dcb4e)

I currently have this code:

```
{***************** CheckALetter ***************}
procedure TForm1.CheckLetter(ch:char);
var
 i:integer;
 s:string;
 goodguess:boolean;
begin
 goodguess:=false;
 if not (ch in GuessedLetters)
 then
 begin
   GuessedLetters:=GuessedLetters+[ch];
   guessesLabel.caption:=guesseslabel.caption+ch+',';
   s:=Wordlabel.caption;
   for i:=1 to length(TheWord) do {see if the letter is in the word}
   begin
     if ch=Theword[i] then
     begin
       s[2*i-1]:=ch; {fill in the  letter in display}
       goodguess:=true;
     end;
   end;
   wordlabel.caption:=s;
   {if not goodguess then drawAPiece(clred);}
   If pos('_',WordLabel.caption)=0 then  {all underscores replaced by letters}
   showmessage('A reprieve!')
   else {If piececount=Hangmanlist.count}
   begin
     showmessage('Oh, oh  Goodbye!'+#13 +'(The word was '+theword+')');
     {deadlbl.visible:=true;}
   end;
 end
 else messagebeep(mb_IconExclamation);
end;

//On key presss
procedure TForm1.guess_typeKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
 key:=upcase(key);
 guess_type.text:='';
 If not (key in ['A'..'Z']) then
 begin
   key:=#00;
   messagebeep(mb_iconexclamation);
 end
 else  CheckLetter(key);
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure where the TMemo fits in. The TMemo.Lines is just a normal TStringList, you can make a fo

```
for i:=1 to MyMemo.Lines.Count do
   s := MyMemo.Lines[i-1];
   // Do somenthing with s..
```